# Strapi React binding with Material UI data table issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am new to react, and I have created a backend with strapi, and I have tested the graphQl query and have checked that it returns back the values of all nodes in the query.

Now to react, I am using the Material UI DataGrid component, and I can populate most of the nodes based upon my query, except for those one with nested nodes.
But in my console log I am returning values for all my nodes, so I guess my problem must be in the code for the data table?

I don't see values for the lead.leadSourceName and all the values for the contact node including the notes node within contact node, all this opens in a modal when a row is clicked. The modal does open but with values as undefined.
Once again, in the console log all values for all nodes are present.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import { Modal, Typography, Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const GET_COMPANIES_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    companies {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          companyName
          status
          internship
          futureMinEmp
          futureMaxEmp
          leads {
            leadSourceName
          }
          contact {
            firstName
            lastName
            jobtitle
            lastContact
            nextContact
            notes {
              date
              note
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const columns = [
    { field: 'companyName', headerName: 'Company Name', flex: 1, headerAlign: 'center' },
    { field: 'status', headerName: 'Status', flex: 1, headerAlign: 'center' },
    { field: 'internship', headerName: 'Internship', flex: 1, headerAlign: 'center' },
    { field: 'futureMinEmp', headerName: 'Min Employees', flex: 1, headerAlign: 'center' },
    { field: 'futureMaxEmp', headerName: 'Max Employees', flex: 1, headerAlign: 'center' },
    {
        field: 'leads',
        headerName: 'Leads',
        flex: 1,
        headerAlign: 'center',
        valueGetter: (params) => {
          const leads = params.row.attributes?.leads;
          if (typeof leads === 'object' && leads !== null && leads.hasOwnProperty('leadSourceName')) {
            console.log('LEADS OBJECT:', leads); // add this line to log the value of the leads object
            return leads.leadSourceName;
          } else {
            return 'No leads';
          }
        },
      },
      
      
  ];

  
  

const CompaniesPage = () => {
  const [selectedContact, setSelectedContact] = useState(null);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_COMPANIES_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  const companies = data?.companies?.data?.map((company) => {
    console.log('Company:', company);
    const leads = Array.isArray(company.attributes?.leads) && company.attributes.leads.length > 0
      ? company.attributes.leads.map((lead) => lead.leadSourceName).join(', ')
      : 'No leads';
    return {
      id: company.id,
      ...company.attributes,
      leads,
    };
  });

  const handleRowClick = (params) => {
    console.log('Selected contact:', params.row.contact);
    setSelectedContact(params.row.contact);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedContact(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DataGrid
  rows={companies}
  columns={columns}
  autoHeight
  onRowClick={handleRowClick}
  getRowClassName={(params) => {
    // add class name to row based on condition
    return params.row.contact ? 'clickable-row' : '';
  }}
/>




      <Modal open={!!selectedContact} onClose={handleCloseModal} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Box bgcolor="background.paper" boxShadow={2} p={2} style={{ outline: 'none' }}>
          <Typography variant="h4">
            {selectedContact ? `${selectedContact.firstName} ${selectedContact.lastName}` : ''}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">{selectedContact ? selectedContact.jobtitle : ''}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{selectedContact ? `Last Contact: ${selectedContact.lastContact}` : ''}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{selectedContact ? `Next Contact: ${selectedContact.nextContact}` : ''}</Typography>
          <ReactMarkdown>{selectedContact?.notes?.[0]?.note}</ReactMarkdown>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default CompaniesPage
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `DataGrid` is applying `stringify` on `contact` object to make it presentable in a cell, therefore, you cannot access inside of it.

Try this instead:

```
const handleRowClick = (params) => {
  console.log('Selected contact:', params.row.contact);
  setSelectedContact(companies.find(company=>company.id === params.row.id).contact);
};
```

Also I recommend removing objects from your rows to prevent this misconseption.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work out either, when the modal opens when clicking on a row, it still displays 4 values as undefined.

Comment: I made an edit: adding `.contact` since the value was `company` instead of `contact`. Please try again

Comment: still same respons

Comment: can you add this and tell me what's the log: `console.log(companies.find(company=>company.id === params.row.id).contact)`

Comment: {__typename: "ComponentContactContactInfo", firstName: "Kalle", lastName: "Anka", jobtitle: "VP", lastContact: "2023-02-04T23:03:00.000Z", …}
1 {__typename: "ComponentContactContactInfo", firstName: "Kajsa", lastName: "Anka", jobtitle: "HR", lastContact: "2023-02-07T23:04:00.000Z", …}

Comment: and within each item of the array: 0 Object

__typename: "ComponentContactContactInfo"

firstName: "Kalle"

jobtitle: "VP"

lastContact: "2023-02-04T23:03:00.000Z"

lastName: "Anka"

nextContact: "2023-04-09T23:39:00.000Z"

notes: Array (2)
0 Object

__typename: "ComponentContactNote"

date: "2023-02-27T23:04:00.000Z"

note: "# Test title↵↵- One↵- Two↵- Three↵↵↵>A apple a day↵↵↵```↵print(f(\"Your name is: {name}\"))↵```"

Object-prototyp
1 {__typename: "ComponentContactNote", date: "2023-03-20T23:13:00.000Z", note: "# Second title↵↵_**A lot of text**_"}

Comment: Well so your `contact` is of type array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252830/discussion-between-mrafei-and-user2371684).

Comment: sent you a message on the chat :)